# Problema al calcular diferencia entre dos fechas en PHP

Tags: php

¿Alguien me puede decir porqué este código imprime **12**?

`$_POST['sdate']` en este ejemplo es: `2018-10-31`

`$_POST['date']` en este ejemplo es: `2019-07-13`

---

```
$startDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $_POST['sdate']);
$endDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $_POST['date']);

$dif2 = date_diff($startDate, $endDate);
$diff2 = $dif2->format('%d');

echo $diff2;
```

Esto me lo calcula mal casi con cualquier fecha, pero he puesto esa de ejemplo porque se ve muy claro que no es correcto (que yo sepa).

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Intentalo asi: `$diff2 = $dif2->format('%R%a');`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EL problema es cómo lo estás mostrando, en lugar de usar %d utiliza %a.

Acá te copio el código funcionando, me devuelve 255 días:

```
$startDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', '2018-10-31');
$endDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', '2019-07-13');

$dif2 = date_diff($startDate, $endDate);
$diff2 = $dif2->format('%a');

echo $diff2;
```

¡Suerte!

Answer (score 1):

intenta con esto a ver

```
function validate_date($d1,$d2){
    $d_1 = explode("-", $d1);
    $d_2 = explode("-", $d2);

for($i = 0; $i <= count($d_1) -1; $i++)
    if($d_1[$i] != $d_2[$i]){
        return false;       
    }
    return true;    
}

if(validate_date('2018-10-31','2018-11-31')){
    echo "es igual";
}
```